# Localization issue in Delphi XE4

Tags: delphi, localization, delphi-xe4

1. Create VCL Forms Application
2. Drop a TLabel component on the form.
3. As per [Adding Languages to a Project](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Seattle/en/Adding_Languages_to_a_Project)
   add language French CANADA and compile the project with this changes.
4. Open .dfm file and change the caption of label under french translation column.
5. Deploy the exe in another machine as mentioned in [Localizing Applications](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Seattle/en/Localizing_Applications)
6. Execute the exe and noticed those junk characters instead of the original string.

When we try to build the exe for French Canada some of the characters(like é) are coming as differently as “Â©”
Which is incorrect.
is there any solution for this?

Comment: Strings are stored in a DFM in UTF-8 format. `Â©` is the UTF-8 encoded form of `é` being incorrectly displayed as Latin-1 instead of as UTF-8. You shouldn't be editing a DFM at all. Did you mean DRC instead?

Comment: As @Remy says, the .dfm isn't yours to edit; it belongs to the IDE, and you should very rarely need to modify it yourself (and then only when you know what you're doing). The .dfm has nothing to do with localization, and therefore your question is based on a non-existent problem.

Comment: i tired changing drc file also. result is same.